# Automatic data refresh for Power BI embedded

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have implemented Power BI embedded in a web app and used the Python script to import the on-premises data to the Power BI.
I use the power BI embedded generated sample .NET file without Channing anything.

**Question:**
Can we do the data automatically refresh without using the on-premises data gateway (personal mode) in the above embedded option?

Can explain how to implement the automatic data refresh for Power BI embedded?

Comment: How are you using python in the loading process? Can you give more detail

Comment: What is the source of data? (CSV, database, etc..?)

Comment: I used the Python script to load the data from Prometheus to the Power BI data model.
(Get Data -> More -> Other -> Python Script)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do automatic data refresh for Power BI embedded without using the on-premises data gateway (personal mode).

**How to implement automatic data refresh for Power BI embedded**

There are two ways to implement automatic data refresh for Power BI embedded:

**1. Using Power BI Premium**

If you have Power BI Premium, you can use the Power BI Embedded service to refresh your datasets automatically. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Power BI Embedded service and sign in with your Power BI account.
2. Click the **Datasets** tab.
3. Select the dataset that you want to refresh automatically.
4. Click the **Edit** button.
5. Under **Scheduled refresh**, select the **Enable scheduled refresh** checkbox.
6. Select the refresh frequency and time that you want.
7. Click **Save**.

**2. Using Power Automate**

If you do not have Power BI Premium, you can use Power Automate to refresh your datasets automatically. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Power Automate website and sign in with your Microsoft account.
2. Click the **Create** button.
3. Select **Automated flow**.
4. Give your flow a name and select a trigger. For example, you could select a trigger that runs every hour.
5. Add an action to your flow. The action you need to add depends on the type of data source that you are using. For example, if you are using a SQL Server data source, you would need to add the **Get data from SQL Server** action.
6. Configure the action to connect to your data source and retrieve the data that you want to refresh.
7. Add another action to your flow. The action you need to add depends on the type of Power BI dataset that you are refreshing. For example, if you are refreshing an import dataset, you would need to add the **Refresh Power BI dataset** action.
8. Configure the action to connect to your Power BI dataset and refresh it.
9. Save your flow.

Once you have saved your flow, it will run automatically based on the trigger that you specified.

**Note:** If you are using the Power BI Embedded generated sample .NET file without changing anything, you will need to modify the code to use Power Automate to refresh your datasets automatically.

**Here are some additional tips for implementing automatic data refresh for Power BI embedded:**

- Make sure that your data source is available and accessible to the Power BI service or Power Automate.
- Test your automatic data refresh process to make sure that it is working correctly.
- Monitor your automatic data refresh process to make sure that it is running as expected.

Comment: Just to note, depending on how python is being used in the loading process, you may have to use the personal gateway.